# I need to add Numlock=on in the [General] section of sddm configuration on Ubuntu Focal, where is sddm.conf?

Tags: 20.04, sddm

I need to add `Numlock=on` in the `[General]` section of the sddm configuration, but I cannot find it :

```bash
$ man sddm.conf | grep -1 sddm.conf
NAME
       sddm.conf - sddm display manager configuration

--

       /usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d
              System configuration directory

       /etc/sddm.conf.d
              Local configuration directory

       /etc/sddm.conf
              Local configuration file for compatibility
$ ls /usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/ /etc/sddm.conf.d/ /etc/sddm.conf
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/etc/sddm.conf.d/': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/etc/sddm.conf': No such file or directory
```

Where is `sddm.conf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a *fresh* Lubuntu 20.04.4 *daily* install ([*it's our next release*](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-4-lts-point-release-status-tracking/26490)) you will find the file `sddm.conf` in the `/etc/` directory, ie.

`/etc/sddm.conf`

Note however, you can experience different locations if you didn't fresh install; but installed an older release & *release-upgraded* to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, ie. your system may be using older location(s).

Comment: I've freshly installed from Ubuntu 20.04.3 ISO., there is no `sddm.conf` anywhere on the FS.

Comment: There doesn't need to be one; `sddm` is used by Lubuntu (LXQt) & Kubuntu (KDE) whom added one with their settings/configs, but they both differ.  The box I'm using now (Lubuntu *jammy*) doesn't contain one either.

Comment: How do I enable a parameter in the sddm configuration without any `sddm.conf` file ?

Comment: Create the file and you'll have one - it's a text file (*the QA-test install I booted to confirm what I wrote contained just two lines inside the file related to theme*)

Comment: Just one more thing : where shall I create my `sddm.conf` file : will it be stored in `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/` directory or in `/etc/sddm.conf.d/` directory or in `/etc/` directory or in `/etc/sddm/conf/` directory ?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop uses `gdm3` by default; I've not *recently* tested it with `sddm` but I'd expect it to work in `/etc/sddm.conf` as that's where it was on the 20.04.4 install performed yesterday I looked at only minutes ago.

Comment: Your answer to the question mentions `/etc/sddm/conf`, did you mean `/etc/sddm.conf` ?

Comment: Thank you heaps @SebMa - Yes I did !!